# Create HTML File with commandline

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm trying to make a HTML file with command line, but there is one problem. I need the quotes otherwise the echo doesn't work. But now the quotes are also displayed on the HTML page. This is my code:

```
FindStr "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" test1.txt

echo "<html><body><table><tr><td>Plugin</td><td>Resultaten</td></tr>" > goedje.html

if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (echo "<tr BGCOLOR="#FF0000"><td>Build</td><td>Fout!</td></tr>" >> goedje.html ) else (echo "<tr BGCOLOR="#00FF00"><td>Build</td><td>Gelukt!</td></tr>" >> goedje.html) 

echo "</table></body></html>" >> goedje.html
```

If i'm doing it without the quotes then the program doesn't run!

Comment: It will not add the quotes to result.html

Comment: Strange.. Because this it the broncode:
"<html><body><table><tr><td>Plugin</td><td>Result</td></tr>" 
"<tr BGCOLOR="#00FF00"><td>Build</td><td>Gelukt!</td></tr>" 
"</table></body></html>"

Comment: the code in this comment is different from that u pasted in the question , pls update that , with real cases only we can give u solution , we cant imagine ur scenario ..

Comment: Updated for you ;-) But I don't think this make any difference..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `windows`, you can use `^` to escape `<` and `>`

```
C:\> echo ^<html^>...^</html^> > result.html
```

Comment: For Dummies (like me): Search & replace for `<` with `^<` and `>` with `^>` will do the job. But don't forget to exclude the redirected output to the file. This last > must not have an escape char.

Answer (score 0):

I quess this can be caused by the shell you are using. Your command works for me. You can try using ' ' quotes instead of " " ones.

Comment: No also the ' doesn't work. I use the Command line of Windows 7.. If I do it without the quotes or with the ' I get this result: < this wasn't expected here

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is to skip the special characters in the shell..

For eg : if you want to print " you should use \"

Like that so many characters need to be skipped using some special sequences

check this link for such details

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html

Hope this will help you..

You can also refer

http://steve-parker.org/sh/escape.shtml

Try this code

```
FindStr "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" test1.txt

echo "<html><body><table><tr><td>Plugin</td><td>Resultaten</td></tr>" > goedje.html

if %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 (echo "<tr BGCOLOR=\"#FF0000\"><td>Build</td><td>Fout\!</td></tr>" >> goedje.html ) else (echo "<tr BGCOLOR=\"#00FF00\"><td>Build</td><td>Gelukt\!</td></tr>" >> goedje.html) 

echo "</table></body></html>" >> goedje.html
```